# Open Windows notepad with Kotlin

Tags: windows, kotlin

I'm new with Kotlin and I'm trying to make a button open Windows notepad.

I'm doing a calculator and I wanted to implement a button to open the notepad, so the user could easily take notes at the moment of using it.

I've tried to directly use Java to execute it in runtime, but I couldn't.

I'm using TornadoFX for the GUI

Also searched for a way to do it on Kotlin, but didn't found anything.

Edit: Sorry for not including any code, but I didn't remember the exact thing I tried and I hadn't my PC, here's what I've tried:

1. Creating a Kotlin function with Java code

   fun apuntes(){
   Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
   Process process = runtime.exec("C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories"
   "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories");
   }
2. Creating a Java class with the exact same code than before, declaring a variable with Kotlin

   var u: Notes = notas()

   fun onAction2(fn2: Notes){
   u = fn
   }

Where **Notes** is a public class and **notas** is a function, then tried this, as it is how I'm working with the calculator buttons:

```
private fun operador(x: String) {
     if (Regex("[0-9]").matches(x)) {
         display.text += x
     } else {
         when(x) {
             "+" -> onAction(sum(displayValue))
             "-" -> onAction(rest(displayValue))
             "/" -> onAction(div(displayValue))
             "%" -> {onAction(sum(displayValue /100)); operador("=")}
             "*" -> onAction(mult(displayValue))
             "C" -> onAction(sum(0))
             "+/-" -> {onAction(sum(-1* displayValue)); operador("=")}
             "Notas" -> onAction2(notes())
             "=" -> display.text = state.calc(displayValue).toString()
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: You have tried Runtime().getRuntime().exec() and it didn't work?

Comment: Please provide a bit more details about what you tried and where you struggle, for instance with code snippets, so that we can help you better

Comment: It shows the following: Cannot acces <init>: it is private in Runtime, and also Unresolved reference: get Runtime. Thanks for the help @IlyaSazonov, I suppose I need to override?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not doing it earlier @Joffrey , but didn't have my computer with me, and didn't remember the code at all

Comment: @Skynotelink, sorry, it should've been Runtime.getRuntime().exec without braces after Runtime . Look at the answer I posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you open notepad with Kotlin

```java
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad")
```

or more modern (and I think better) solution

```java
ProcessBuilder("notepad").start()
```

Comment: Much appreciated! Worked as wanted